# Generic JSON response with @JsonProperty

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, web-services, generic-programming

I am looking to dynamically set the json keys being returned by a web service. Is there any way to dynamically set the values in JsonProperty? I can dynamically get a list of the values needed to be return once the UI call hits the controller. If not, is there any other known way? It’s basically setting an object on the fly and sending it back to the UI without a model.

Comment: Can you show the code you're using?

Comment: Unfortunately I can’t. Let me try to clarify above though

Comment: @Jason essentially I am getting the data back in json format from the DB. I can get an array list of the keys back for the object and then parse the Json documents returned from the DB based on that list of keys. So once I have the list of keys and list of values I want to build an object using those values only. The UI is using the keys to dynamically build a grid based on the names being returned. This is trying to be very generic and flexible so we can display in the UI, no matter what data is being called, dynamically without further development.

Answer (score 0):

I have two ideas about how to do that:

1) You can create one model with all fields and configure ObjectMapper to return only not null field. Then you can set only required fields and they will be serialized to json.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```

2) You can use Map instead of your object. Just put required field into Map and they will be serialized into Json.